# How to deploy Contextual Gadget on Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget

I have developed a Contextual Gadget and installed it in my domain. It is working fine in my domain, but it is not working outside of my domain. How can I access my gadget outside my domain?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your Google Apps domain? According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#what_is_a_gmail_contextual_gadget) you can only deploy contextual gadgets within a single organization, or list for sale in the Google Apps marketplace.